# adressing object by variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

In my form I have a number of 8 text fields named with consecutive numbers (tbx_MyID**1** to tbx_MyID**8**). I want to loop through all 8 text fields to create new records out of the text fields' values. So I am trying to store the text fields names in a variable and address the text fields by this variable. This only creates an error, saying the object does not exist.

```
Private Sub btn_Enter_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl")

    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1
    While x < 9
        Dim y As String
        y = "tbx_MyID" & x
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields("ID") = Me!y.Value
        x = x+1
     Wend

    rs.Update
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close 

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify it is a control. Me.Controls(y).value

Comment: You can also iterate through controls by defining a variant and using a for each statement with .name to get the control name

Comment: By the way, why are you assigning the same value to rs.Fields("ID")? You are assigning to the same field.

Comment: Are you creating 8 new records (and each text box has a different ID), or 1 record with 8 fields?

Comment: 8 new records with the IDs taken from the 8 text boxes (fields or boxes?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted previously, you need to access the form's [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.controls) property.

Additionally, you probably want to store your text box prefix and the number of text boxes in constants, to make your code more readable.

Finally, [even Microsoft suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/whilewend-statement) you replace `While...Wend` loops with the `Do...Loop` construct. So updated code might look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const TEXT_BOX_PREFIX As String = "tbx_MyID"
Private Const TEXT_BOX_COUNT As Integer = 8

Private Sub Command18_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim txtBox As Access.TextBox

    For x = 1 To TEXT_BOX_COUNT
        Set txtBox = Me.Controls(TEXT_BOX_PREFIX & x)

        Debug.Print txtBox.Value
        ' put your code to add/update records here.
    Next x
End Sub
```

If you clarify your question to indicate how specifically the text boxes relate to new records, I can update my answer to address that part.

Comment: I am somewhat new to vba and the while loop is something that works in nearly every language I know, that is why I started there. But thanks for the hint, I will replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `rs.Fields("ID") = Me!y.Value`

with `rs.Fields("ID") = Me.Controls("tbx_MyID" & x)`

It will work because the default property of the underlying control type (a text box) is the "Text" property.

There are a lot of ways to reference controls dynamically on a form. It might be clearer to declare a variable for the text box, get a reference to it, and then specifically reference the Text property:

```
Dim ctl As TextBox
Dim x As Integer

x = 1
While x < 9
ctl = Me.Controls("tbx_MyID" & x)
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("ID") = ctl.Text
    x = x+1
Wend
```